# Calculate the total annual sum for the previous year in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

How can I calculate the **total annual sum for the last year**? Specifically, I need to calculate last year's total sales.

Here's what I do:

```
total_sales_last_year =
CALCULATE(
  SUM(fact_sale_order[sales_amount]),
  DATEADD(dim_date[formatted_date], -1, YEAR),
  REMOVEFILTERS(dim_date[month_name])
)
```

However, if for example, I filter for January, in sales_last_year I won't get the sales of the whole year, but I will only have those of January 2021. The result **I'm looking for is the total of the previous year**.

Comment: How about providing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @Peter I just created an example .pbix for you. Thank you so much for your time! https://drive.google.com/file/d/13lRg1KAeb4VVxadDFiPk7jmyQqMfMPiB/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```html
total_sales = 
VAR last_year = YEAR(MAX(dim_date[formatted_date]))-1

VAR sales_last_year =
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(fact_sale_order[sales_amount]),
        FILTER(ALLEXCEPT(dim_date, dim_date[year]), YEAR(dim_date[formatted_date]) = last_year )
    )

VAR sales_current_year =
CALCULATE(
    SUM(fact_sale_order[sales_amount]),
    DATESYTD(dim_date[formatted_date])
)
RETURN sales_last_year + sales_current_year
```